# Does it make sense to write non-linear functions from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as matrices?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Say the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=(x+\sin(y) + \log(z), e^z - y^3 + \frac{1}{x})$.

\begin{bmatrix}
    x       & \sin(y) & \log(z)  \\
    \frac1x       & -y^3 & e^z  \\
\end{bmatrix}

Can I look at this in the way I would have looked at it in linear algebra? The rows seem to be the component functions, and the columns seem to be how the function acts on the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is there anything to gain, by writing this in this way?

Comment: This notation might be misleading: you don't get the value of the function $f$ at a point in $\mathbb R^3$ by applying the matrix you've written down to the vector. It looks like you're defining a family of linear functions, parameterized by $\mathbb R^3$. But my understanding is you want to use this as a notational tool for a single non-linear function, which is different.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to lead anywhere. In particular, almost no functions $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ can be written this way, how would you go about $$(x,y,z) \mapsto (\sin(x+y + z), \cos(x + z) + y)?$$ Your way of splitting only works if your function is given by six maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which you add; this is a very special case and (without prior motivation) maybe not worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

That notation works for separable functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $  $$f(x_1, x_2,...x_n)  = f_1 (x_1) + f_2(x_2) + ... + f_n (x_n) $$  where $f_i :\Bbb R \to \Bbb{R^m}$

Then associated matrix is  $A_f (x) := [f(x_1) , f(x_2), ...,  f(x_n)]$ i.e., the i's th column of $A_f (x)$ is $f_i (x_i).$

You can check that this notation is compatible with addition , subtraction, and pointwise product of matrices. And the most significant thing about notation is that $\text{Jackob}(f) = A_f ' $